# ng-repeat filtering data by date range using ui bootstrap date

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, datepicker

I want  to be able to  filter a list that contains a time stamp by selecting a date range from the ui bootstrap datepicker.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for a Loan Application" ng-model="Loansearch">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select ng-model="Loansearch.mambu_account_state" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">All Applications</option>
                            <option value="Active">Active</option>
                            <option value="PARTIAL APPLICATION">Partial Application</option>
                            <option value="PENDING APPROVAL">Pending Approval</option>
                            <option value="CLOSE">Close</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"
                               uib-datepicker-popup="dd-mm-yyyy"

                               ng-model="date1"
                               is-open="popup2.opened"
                               datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                               ng-required="true"
                               close-text="Close"
                               alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
                               placeholder="From: dd-mm-yyyy"
                               ng-click="open2()"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"
                               uib-datepicker-popup="dd-mm-yyyy"

                               ng-model="date2"
                               is-open="popup1.opened"
                               datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                               ng-required="true"
                               close-text="Close"
                               alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
                               placeholder="To: dd-mm-yyyy"
                               ng-click="open1()"
                        />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                    <td>Loan Account ID</td>
                    <td>Loan Amount</td>
                    <td>Created At</td>
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="loan in loans|filter:(!!Loansearch || undefined) && Loansearch :true">
                    <td>@{{ loan.customer.user.first_name }}</td>
                    <td>@{{ loan.customer.user.last_name}}</td>
                    <td>@{{ loan.mambu_loan_account_id }}</td>
                    <td>@{{ loan.mambu_account_state }}</td>
                    <td>@{{ loan.created_at | dateFormat}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
```

Additionally, I want to be able to fill the "From" field with the a value from the datepicker and also in the "To" field as well, so to get only the records that are in this range.

Comment: It would be easier to assist you if there were a plunker with your controller code.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i understand the question right but try this:
inject ui.bootstrap to your angular app and change this line

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for a Loan Application" ng-model="Loansearch">
```

with this

```
<uib-datepicker ng-model="Loansearch" class="well well-sm" ></uib-datepicker>
```

and change the ng-repeat section to this

```
ng-repeat="loan in loans|dateFilter:Loansearch:'created_at'"
```

and i wrote a simple filter, add this filter to your app

```
myApp.filter('dateFilter',function(){
 return function(items,key,field){
     return items.filter(function(item){
      return key?(item[field].toString().slice(0,10)==key):true;
     });
  };
})
```